# SQL BETWEEN offset upbound or not

Tags: sql, between

To search for movies that begin with the letters 'D', 'E', and 'F' my code is

```
SELECT *
FROM movies
WHERE name BETWEEN 'D%' AND 'G%';
```

Why is 'G' the upbound instead of 'F', especially when the upbound in the following code is 1979 instead of 1980 to look for movies from the 70s?  Why does the first example need to be offset by one while the example below doesn't?

```
SELECT *
FROM movies
WHERE year BETWEEN 1970 and 1979;
```

Comment: You have a misunderstanding resulting in you mixing BETWEEN with LIKE. The 'D%' and 'G%' are intended for LIKE only. BETWEEN literally reads what you're giving it, and, because of this misunderstanding, the result appears confusing, some of the answers already posted, partially clarifies this misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

The BETWEEN function works the same for text and numeric values, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720950/sql-between-for-text-vs-numeric-values). It is inclusive for both the top and the bottom of the range. I'd check a couple of things:

- Are you sure that you have movies which start with G? Otherwise that'll definitely return only D through F.
- When you use the F letter, does your code look like this:
  `SELECT * FROM movies WHERE name BETWEEN 'D%' AND 'F%';`

If not, try using the `~` character, like `SELECT * FROM movies WHERE name BETWEEN 'D' AND 'G~'`. Alternatively, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980783/sql-between-clause-with-strings-columns?noredirect=1&lq=1) has some other details which might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
name between 'D' and 'G'
```

is equivalent to

```
name>='D' and name<='G'
```

In this example, `Dark Knight` would work but `Goat` wont because `Goat > G`

The expression

```
name between '1970' and '1979'
```

is equivalent to

```
name>='1970' and name<='1979'
```

`1979 <= 1979` works!