# Strange behaviour of Sql query with between operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is this strange error in sql query.

The query is something like this.

```
select * from student where dob between '20150820' and '20150828'
```

But in the database the column of dob is varchar(14) and is in yyyyMMddhhmmss format,Say my data in the row is (20150827142545).If i fire the above query it should not retrive any rows as i have mentioned yyyyMMdd format in the query.But it retrives the row with yesterday date (i.e 20150827112535) and it cannot get the records with today's date (i.e 20150828144532)

Why is this happening??

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: You do string comparison not date, convert to date and should work. And for future please don't store date as `VARCHAR(14)`

Comment: Alter column to date type!

Comment: There is nothing strange going on.  If you store a date as a varchar you cannot expect it to behave like a date.

Comment: Thanks for giving suggestions..... Data type cannot be converted since it is in production now.. @jarlh

Comment: @Fred right I agree ... But why is it showing me the records of yesterday?? This is my actual question..

Comment: Don't misunderstand the question ..Here i am WHY not HOW :)

Comment: Take a look at this post.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980783/sql-between-clause-with-strings-columns  It gives an explanation how strings are compared using between.

Comment: Thank you Fred....I got the reason Why this hapenning.Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
select * from student 
where convert(date,LEFT(dob,8)) between 
      convert(date'20150820')  and convert(date,'20150828'))
```

Also as others have commented you need to store your date as `Date` instead of `varchar` to avoid such problems in future.

Comment: Thank you..... But my question is why is it showing records for yesterday's date with my wrong query??

Comment: @BhanuChowdary:- The reason is probably because `BETWEEN` is asymmetric in SQL Server and dates were compared as strings not as a dates

Comment: :- Yeah ..true.. Dates are compared as strings but why and how is the query giving me the records between those dates exclusive of the dates specified in the query and, even the strings are in yyyyMMddhhmmss format.But In the query I have specified in yyyyMmdd format only.How is it making a match for the records between the specified dates??

Comment: @BhanuChowdary:- Its probably because `BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of test_expression is greater than or equal to the value of begin_expression and less than or equal to the value of end_expression.` So in your case it is matching the first 8 characters and returns true and so you are getting the result.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned you would need to use the correct date type to have between behave properly.

```
select *
from student 
where convert(date,LEFT(dob,8)) between '20150820' and '20150828'
```

Sidenote: You don't have to explicitly convert your two dates from text as this will be done implicitly as long as you use an unambiguous date representation, i.e. the ISO standard 'YYYYMMDD' or 'YYYY-MM-DD'. Of course if you're holding the values in variables then use date | datetime datatype

```
declare @startdate date
declare @enddate date

select *
from student 
where convert(date,LEFT(dob,8)) between @startdate and @enddate
```

Sidenote 2: Performing the functions on your table dob column would prevent any indexes on that column from being used to their full potential in your execution plan and may result in slower execution, if you can, define the correct data type for the table dob column or use a persistent computed column or materialised view if your performance is a real issue.

Sidenote 3: If you need to maintain the time portion in your data i.e. date and time of birth, use the following to ensure all records are captured;

```
select *
from student
where
convert(date,LEFT(dob,8)) >= '20150820'
    and convert(date,LEFT(dob,8)) < dateadd(d,1,'20150828')
```

Comment: Thank you Edward.... I know it can be done using convert function ...But my question here is that how is the query behaving if it is of type  varchar...Why is it showing me the records between those days exclusive of the dates i have mentioned in the query ..

Comment: I see what your asking, well I understand that when comparing character data it would start from the very left string and when strings are of unequal length the longer string is treated as being after. This is why your first date appears and second doesn't. In other words AB comes before ABC and ABC comes before AC and the same for numbers 12 comes before 123 and 123 comes before 13. Back to your original data 20150827142545 is between  20150827[------] and 20150828[------] whilst 20150828144532 comes after 20150828[------] and is therefore excluded from the result set.

Comment: Also, I think that the ordering of character data is defined by the character set in use and areas such as case sensitivity can come into play. I'm trying to find the links to back this up

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to convert first the string to date.

```
select * 
from student 
where dob between convert(date, '20150820') and convert(date, '20150828')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why is this happening?**

The comparison is executed from left to right and the order of characters is determined by the codepage in use.

> Sort Order
>
> Sort order specifies the way that data values are sorted, affecting
>   the results of data comparison. The sorting of data is accomplished
>   through collations, and it can be optimized using indexes.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx

Answer (score -2):

There are problems with between in T-SQL.

But if you want a fast answer convert to date first and use >= <= or even datediff to compare - maybe write a between function yourself if you want the easy use like between and no care about begin and start times ...

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)