# is that possible to count how many rows between two rows mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table like below. I want to count how many rows between berry and strawberry, in my case is 2 rows between these two fruits. How can I achieve that?

```html
id   fruit
1     apple
2     berry
3     banana
4     pineapple
5     strawberry
```

Comment: Can you show us your mysql query?

Comment: `select count(id) from fruits where id > (select id from fruits where fruit='berry') and id<(select id from fruits where fruit='strawberry')`

Comment: Ordered by what? Insertion order? There is no guarantee that mysql will return the rows in the order they were inserted.

Comment: @Cfreak yes that is a main point.

Comment: @TintuCRaju you probably have the best answer, though requires auto-increment. (Though one usually assumes that with mysql :) )

Comment: I just want to count how many row between two rows, don't need by order, or do I?

Comment: @conan you can't because mysql doesn't have any concept of order unless you specify an order.  Since it appears you're using auto_increment, that's the best way to do it.

Comment: This question is tough, however ask yourself again, do you have to do this way, or do you have an alternative way to get what you wanted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query,

```
  $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total_count FROM table_name JOIN ( SELECT MAX(id) as 
  maxid,MIN(id) as minid FROM `table_name` WHERE fruit = 'berry' OR 
  fruit= 'strawberry') as temp ON table_name.id > temp.minid AND 
  table_name.id<temp.maxid";
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write query similar to this-

```
$sql = select * from table where fruit between 'berry' and 'strawberry';
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$rows =  mysql_num_rows($result);
```

here is the reference-
[SQL Between clause with strings columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980783/sql-between-clause-with-strings-columns)

Comment: your answer is very good. I was wondering. how about I change my table a little bit that two value are same. What if id 2 is strawberry, id 5 is strawberry?

Comment: FYI This will give the row difference resulting from an alphabetical ordering of the table.