# how to search Year between in Dynamic Linq

Tags: performance, linq

I have YearField which is string in my database. I want to write a function to allow user to be able to search that YearField with Between.

```
string fromYear = tbxFromYear.Text;
string toYear = tbxToYear.Text;
searchQuery = "Convert.ToInt32(YearField) > (@0) && Convert.ToInt32(YearField) < (@1)";

var result = db.selectDataFromSharedView().AsQueryable().
                   Where(searchQuery, Convert.ToInt32(fromYear),Convert.ToInt32(ToYear)).OrderBy("YearField Descending").ToList();
```

I got the following error in dynamic linq line.

***No applicable method 'ToInt32' exists in type 'Convert'***

I also replace searchQuery with the following, but not working and the same error comes up.

```
searchQuery = "Convert.ToInt32(\"YearField\") > (@0) && Convert.ToInt32(\"YearField\") < (@1)";
```

Comment: Why convert to an int? Years order correctly as strings if they are all four digits.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980783/sql-between-clause-with-strings-columns

Comment: I tried by your link. But now work. I replace Dynamic Linq Where statement with the following...
Where("YearField between (@1) and  (@2)", tbxFromYear.Text, tbxToYear.Text).OrderBy("YearField Descending").ToList();
This error ***Expression of type 'Boolean' expected*** occurs.

Comment: Why do you use dynamic LINQ, not regular LINQ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
int fromYear = Convert.ToInt32(tbxFromYear.Text);
int toYear = Convert.ToInt32(tbxToYear.Text);

var values = new[] {fromYear, toYear };

searchQuery = "Convert.ToInt32(YearField) > @0 AND Convert.ToInt32(YearField) < @1";

var result = db.selectDataFromSharedView().AsQueryable()
                  .Where(searchQuery, values )
                  .OrderBy("YearField Descending")
                  .ToList();
```