# BETWEEN IN in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have my_own table with  columns - PersonID, FirstName, LastName, City, age and WorkStatus. Write BETWEEN IN syntax with WHERE condition, it doesn't return any rows but doesn't give any error.

```
SELECT PersonID,FirstName,LastName,City,age,WorkStatus
FROM sakila.my_own
WHERE (FirstName BETWEEN 'Omer' AND 'Amrah')
AND NOT WorkStatus IN ('Unemployee');
```

Why does it do that? If any one has any answer, please share with me.
Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: Explain something to us in plain English - What do you expect `FirstName BETWEEN 'Omer' AND 'Amrah'` to do ?

Comment: Possibly duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980783/sql-between-clause-with-strings-columns

Answer (score -1):

You are comparing string using `BETWEEN`.

So obviously it will did not compare it as numeric or date field.

And one more thing

```
AND NOT WorkStatus IN ('Unemployee');
```

Instead of this you have to put

```
AND WorkStatus NOT IN ('Unemployee');
```

Answer (score -1):

you query:

```
  SELECT PersonID,FirstName,LastName,City,age,WorkStatus
    FROM sakila.my_own
    WHERE (FirstName BETWEEN 'Omer' AND 'Amrah')
```

is syntactically correct but not semantically correct. More specifically the clause: `FirstName BETWEEN 'Omer' AND 'Amrah'` will always result in an empty set, because `'Omer' > 'Amrah'`, string wise. Try:

```
FirstName BETWEEN   'Amrah' AND 'Omer'
```

Comment: At downvoters: I would really appreciate if you could justify the downvote.

Answer (score -1):

You should change that `BETWEEN` condition to using `LIKE` operator like

```
WHERE FirstName LIKE '%Omer%' Or FirstName LIKE '%Amrah%'
AND WorkStatus <> 'Unemployee';
```