# Between operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like, between

```
create table timepass
(
    first varchar(50)
);

insert into timepass values('ABCD');
insert into timepass values('A');
insert into timepass values('Dx');
insert into timepass values('D');

SELECT first
FROM timepass
WHERE first BETWEEN 'A%' AND 'D%';
```

I read that the output of between operator includes the values which is mentioned in between clause (inclusive).

Here the output is

```
ABCD
D
```

Here A is not included but D is included. I am not able to understand this behavior. Can someone please explain this ?

Here is the sql fiddle link :- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf5cd5/1/0

Comment: --WHERE first BETWEEN 'A%' AND 'D%'; translates to >= A and <=D
Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980783/sql-between-clause-with-strings-columns

Comment: `WHERE first like 'A%' or first like 'D%';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not using `like` so '%' is treated as a regular character, you are retrieving strings   greater than 'A%' up to 'D%'

'A' < 'A%'

make an insert of 'A%' and try again

maybe this will bring your desired results

```
SELECT first
FROM timepass
WHERE first between 'A' and 'D'
```

Comment: I think `WHERE first >= 'A' and first < 'E'` is more likely to be what's intended.

Answer (score 2):

If you insert an other sample data as follows

```
insert into timepass values('A%');
```

And now execute query

```
SELECT first
FROM timepass
WHERE first between 'A%' and 'D%'
```

Then you might understand how BETWEEN works here. '%' is not a wildcard in this case

Comment: Generally speaking, you don't change data to match the query :)