# Using BETWEEN for dates stored as string in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

The date field in the database tables I am currently working on is in the form of varchar and given in a dd.mm.yyyy format.

For example date : 03.02.2018

There is screen above

[image: date format picture]

So when I send to data with ajax is not working correctly.

There are code below

```
function clean($data) {
    global $con;
    $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, strip_tags($data));
    return $data;
}
$start_date = clean($_POST['start']);
$end_date   = clean($_POST['end']);

if (isset($start_date) && isset($end_date)) {
    $get_date = "SELECT * FROM records WHERE reservations BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' ";
}
```

Start date and End Date are same working for example today or yesterday. But when dates are different dont work for example start date : 03.02.2018 end date :03.03.2018

Best Regards

Thank you.

Comment: That's not an actual `date`-field in the database, is it? MySQL stores dates in the format: `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: You cannot use `BETWEEN` for `varchar` column type in MySQL, you need some workaround.

Comment: Also, avoid to store dates as string, that is bad practice

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson yes column not date format it is varchar store date/ MySQL stores dates in format same DD.MM.YYYY

Answer (score 3):

You'll solve this problem and other issues in the future if you use a `DATE` column type rather than varchar. This would let you use the date functions in MySQL.

If for some reason you can't or wont you'll need to convert the column to a date before doing the `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT * FROM records 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(reservations,'%d.%m.%Y') 
BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date';--Don't use variables directly
```

Additionally you don't want to use raw inputs in your database query. A malicious user could send SQL to your database and cause damage.

It's better to use escaping, or even better to user parameterized queries. There are questions on this site that can help with that.

Comment: This is good solution for this case, although, it should be avoided to store date as string in db if possible at first place.

Comment: @Jim When change to code I give this error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'STR_TO_DATE('01,5,2013','%d.%m.%Y') BETWEEN '' AND ''' at line 2

Comment: I've switched this to use the reservations field but this is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query is using table "reservations" but in images, you are using "rezervasyon_tarihi".
Maybe it should be "SELECT * FROM records WHERE rezervasyon_tarihi BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' ";

And so, I think this topic will help you [SQL Between clause with strings columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980783/sql-between-clause-with-strings-columns)

Comment: Ok thank you for your suggestion. I know There are similar situation column. But now I dont work on pictures column. Thanks you again.