# Best way to filter data for a given range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to find Claims from a given table having a procedure code between the range 'Q5000' and 'Q5090'. I am able to write a function for Int codes but am not sure how to best deal with characters range in SQL Server?

I can manually write all the codes and filter them but is there any way by which I provide the first and Last Value and SQL generates the full set of values.

```
Select * 
from   dbo.claims 
where  ProcedureCode in ('Q5000',Q5001','Q5002',....,'Q5090')
```

Comment: Please show your query and explain the issue that you encountered. Also include some sample data and expected result

Comment: Select * from dbo.claims where ProcedureCode in ('Q5000',Q5001','Q5002',....,'Q5090')  
I have similar range of conditions that need to be applied and typing every code inside an IN condition will take a lot of effort. So was hoping to apply some kind of function that can perform this!

Comment: you can use `WHERE ProcedureCode BETWEEN 'Q5000' AND 'Q5090'`  or use the `>=` and `<=` operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5981101/9870193) in another thread may be helpful for you.

OR

You could also try this assuming same single char is the beginning char.

`SELECT * FROM dbo.claims WHERE RIGHT(ProcedureCode, LEN(ProcedureCode)-1) BETWEEN 5000 AND 5090`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this simple hack

SELECT *
FROM dbo.claims
WHERE ProcedureCode LIKE 'Q50__'
AND TRY_CONVERT(INT, RIGHT(ProcedureCode, 2)) < 91;

Answer (score 0):

If the strings have the same length, and start with the same letters?
Then you can simply use `BETWEEN`.

```
Select * 
from   dbo.claims 
where  ProcedureCode BETWEEN 'Q5000' AND 'Q5090'
```

You see, the problem with character compare is when the length's differ.

For example, the string '2' is bigger than the string '10'.
Because the character '2' comes after '1'.
But 'A02' is smaller than 'A10'.